# tracer(False) bug in Python 3.6.2

Tags: python-3.x, graphics, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to use the Turtle library to recursively draw fractals. I have a function `Koch(step, degree)` which takes in the step size and degree; inside the function, it calls itself with `Koch(step/3, degree-1)` to recursively build the fractal-like sides.

Everything is working great when I have animation enabled, but when I try and toggle `tracer(False)` to speed up the higher level degree drawings, it seems to skip a portion of the animation at the end.

Here is a degree 3 curve, with the animation turned on:
[image: deg3, animation True]

Here is the same curve, but with `tracer(False)`:
[image: deg3, animation False]

The issue persists, no matter the degree of the fractal. Here's the output for the degree 5 curves:
[image: deg5, animation Ture]

[image: deg5, animation False]

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to create a bunch of frames for an animation, and so I need them to draw as fast as possible, or I'll never be able to finish the project.

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Sorry I didn't include any code snippets; I am still new to programming, and especially to Stack Overflow. Seems like someone else was able to help me solve my problem nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least a couple of ways you can fix this.  One is to simpy reset `tracer()` to its original value at the end of your drawing.  I.e. `tracer(1)`.  (As you discovered, to simplify things, you can use `tracer(False)` to hide drawing and `tracer(True)` to turn it back on.)

Another way is to call `update()` at the end of your drawing.  Either should force out the final drawing steps.

Simulating your problem using the koch snowflake example from [python-with-science](http://python-with-science.readthedocs.io/en/latest/koch_fractal/koch_fractal.html) since you didn't supply any code.  Without turning `tracer()` back on nor calling `update()`:

```
from turtle import *

def koch(distance, order):
    if order > 0:
        for angle in [60, -120, 60, 0]:
            koch(distance / 3, order - 1)
            left(angle)
    else:
        forward(distance)

# Choose size
size = 400
order = 3

# Ensure snowflake is centered
penup()
backward(size / 1.732)
left(30)
pendown()

# Make it fast
tracer(False)
hideturtle()

# Three Koch curves
for _ in range(3):
    koch(size, order)
    right(120)

mainloop()
```

[image]

Now just change the ending slightly:

```
# Three Koch curves
for _ in range(3):
    koch(size, order)
    right(120)

# Make the last parts appear
update()

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to this question; I got bogged down with other work. This `update()` trick was exactly what I needed. It even solved some issues I was having with `hideturtle()` as well. Thank you so much!